# How To Create A Line Chart From Array Of Values?

Tags: c#, charts

i want to add line with values on chart

how do this

my array value {10,20,30.....}

[image]

Comment: Is the picture what you have achieved or what you want to do?

Comment: So what have you written so far??

Comment: For a Series S1 try something like this: `for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++)
{    int p = S1.Points.AddXY(i, 123);
    S1.Points[p].Label = i+""; }`

Answer (score 3):

This will bind all your data from the array to the chart in only one line of code:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(insertYourArrayHere);
```