# Improving UI performance for displaying dynamic real-time data

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I'm currently working on a deep reinforcement learning implementation. To see how the training progresses, I created the UI seen below. The textbox and both charts are update each time at the end of a while-loop. This loops is run inside a thread, which simulates a slot machine and trains a neural network. The performance profiler indicates that 87% of CPU usage are consumed by the main thread (running the UI) and the rest is left for the simulation thread.

Does anybody know of a good approach to dramatically shrink down the cost of the UI?

```
    private delegate void AppendChartCallback(Chart chart, double x, double y);
    private void AppendChart(Chart chart, double x, double y)
    {
        if (chart.InvokeRequired)
        {
            AppendChartCallback d = new AppendChartCallback(AppendChart);
            Invoke(d, new object[] { chart, x, y });
        }
        else
        {
            chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);

            if (chart.Series[0].Points.Count % 20 == 0)
            {
                chart.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

edit: I suspended the charts' updates and call individually refresh now as soon as some more amount of data is added (based on modulo).

[image]

Comment: I assume each call to add points to the chart is causing a redraw. What chart control are you using? Is it possible to defer redraws so that the chart is tran periodically instead of each time the series is updated?

Comment: Batch the calls would be the first thing to try. Probably not needed to dispatch every single value immediately, that will take lots of cycles

Comment: Control used
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Comment: Worst case scenario you batch the updates, this can be as simple as updating an array when the data comes in but having a task running that copies the array and uses that as the data source for the grid every 2/3 seconds. The grid will only redraw when the data changes. Using bindings will help since the binding logic in the control will defer draws when you change the data source.

Comment: Joe Albahari gives some useful information on how spinning (aka infinite looping without giving a chance for system idling) can eat up CPU cycles like the Cookie Monster. The problem is, if your main thread is doing the spinning, you can't really have it go idle (the app would freeze). You really should have another thread do the spinning, and use the main thread solely for UI visual updates, for this functionality. Using a timer might help (notice how the timer always does its thing in a thread of its own), but seriously, you don't get the fine grained control, so be mindful of that.

Comment: The slot machine spins in its own thread.The UI is run by the main thread. The timing is not the perfect solution, because the longer the app runs, the more data is to be plotted. So over time, it takes much more time to update the graphs. I implemented something similar to the timing (see above the modulo condition)

Answer (score 0):

I would not plot individual (x,y) points, you can bind to an array of values. There is an example here [How To Create A Line Chart From Array Of Values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828236/how-to-create-a-line-chart-from-array-of-values)

Comment: DataBindY replaces the points. As the data comes in dynamically and growths, this is not the behavior I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add the points to a list.

Have a timer invalidate the view every 16.66 ms.